# Lenovo IdeaPad-5-15IIL05 there is no sound, the touchpad does not work, the brightness adjustment does not work through FN

Tags: release-hera, sound, touchpad, lenovo

I bought **Lenovo IdeaPad-5-15IIL05**, installed **elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera**:

1. No sound (no sound output device).
2. The touchpad does not work.
3. The brightness adjustment through FN does not work.
4. alsamixer does not open, writes no directory

**Please help with the solution of this issue.**

Changed the core of i8042.reset quiet splash (sudo nano / etc / default / grub) - **the result does not work.**

Sound card:

```
Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 34c8 (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3841
```

Touchpad not showing

```
$ lspci
00: 00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a12 (rev 03)
00: 02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)
00: 04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00: 0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a13 (rev 03)
00: 14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00: 14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00: 14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 34f0 (rev 30)
00: 15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller # 0 (rev 30)
00: 15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller # 1 (rev 30)
00: 16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 34e0 (rev 30)
00: 17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
00: 1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00: 1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00: 1f. 3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 34c8 (rev 30)
00: 1f. 4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00: 1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01: 00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Device 1e0f: 0001
```

Comment: May I kindly ask you to type this in terminal:
sudo update-initramfs -u
Copy results, paste it in pastebin.com and provide a link to a pastebin, please?
We will see what firmware is missing.

Comment: Inserted
https://pastebin.com/wbbQxtfA

Answer (score 1):

> sudo update-initramfs -u

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.7.1-050701-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_33.0.4.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.0.12.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_06.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Thanks. I will provide a solution today. I already fixed this and I have the tutorial.

Comment: Thank! I'm waiting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
1. cd /home/yourusername/Downloads/

2. mkdir i915

3. cd /i915/

4. git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

5. sudo cp -R ./linux-firmware/i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/

6. sudo update-initramfs -u
```

It was made a corection in line 5.

Comment: `: ~ / Downloads / i915 $ sudo cp -R /linux-firmware/i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/`

`cp: failed to execute stat for '/ linux-firmware / i915 / *': No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you perform each command separately exactly the way I described one by one? You are doing it wrong. I provided the instruction how it should be done correctly. Do not try to make it in a different way, please.

Comment: I did everything according to the instructions one by one line on the points, the error goes on point 5

```cp: failed to execute stat for '/ linux-firmware / i915 / *': No such file or directory```

Comment: I did everything. He went to a folder under the administrator and simply copied it with a replacement for new files from what he downloaded.

Then did: 

```sudo update-initramfs -u```

Touchpad not working

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have installed Hera on an Ideapad 100S-11IBY and there is no sound. The sound settings screen frist shows there is no audio device but in a few moments it switches to Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (???)

I have tried your solution, but I am getting the same error.
additional note, even though I run command with sudo it does not ask for the password.

the issue of cp is the way you typed the source directory /firmware-linux... it is looking for it in the root directory instead of current folder.
when I changed the line to this:

sudo cp -R firmware-linux/i915/* /lib/firmawere/i915

it ran correctly.

after the full process I have rebooted but I am still getting the No output device screen

Comment: Good afternoon! The solution with sound is here <https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci>, I succeeded, there is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"
```

And save the change. Exit gedit.

Then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and Reboot.

You can check if soundcards are detected with:

```
aplay -l
```

If you do not have gedit, you can use nano instead gedit.

If

```
psmouse.elantech_smbus=0
```

will not work, remove it and instead add this:

```
i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset
```

Solution with i8042 taken from here: [click](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/what-does-the-i8042-nomux-1-kernel-option-do-during-booting-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank! this solution works, there is sound!

How to enable the touchpad?

Comment: I edited my answer above. Add psmouse.elantech_smbus=0 in /etc/default/grub and perform update-grub once again.

Comment: Additionally you can check errors with touchpad in terminal : sudo dmesg | grep -i elantech.

Comment: ```i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop``` - doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try psmouse.elantech_smbus=0 instead of i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop? I mean remove i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop and add psmouse.elantech_smbus=0

Comment: Yes of course ```psmouse.elantech_smbus = 0``` wrote separately

Comment: Is it really possible to turn on the touchpad? Or you can throw the laptop away because they will not accept it back. Lenovo sends to the developers of the system, because everything works for them on windows.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know this. Lenovo has driver for Windows but they did not write the driver for Linux. Eventually you can try to install Linux Mint for example and check is it working there. I am not a Linux drivers expert unfortunately.

Comment: Eventually I can search within next few days the solution. Bear in mind that I work with Red Hat mostly and Solaris, and have Elementary OS Hera installed with the kernel 5.7.0. In my DELL Inspiron 5767 touchpad was working from the beginning.

Comment: Installed Windows 10, everything works. Thanks to all!

Comment: Hah. The best answer I have ever seen. Seems Elementary OS and even Cannonical from Ubuntu have a really lot of work to do and need learn a lot to make it work on every machine like Microsoft did with cooperation with many companies which produce hardware. Thanks that they were able to create Windows drivers (firmware in Linux). Besides do not forget that Linux was in use most of time on servers/desktops where sound card and touch screen or touch pad were not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

`psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` - this option does not work

`i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset` - this option does not work

`sudo dmesg | grep -i elantech` - does not execute a command

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from this post.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227972/touchpad-of-lenovo-ideapad-s145-15iil-not-detected-in-18-04-and-19-10-ubuntu-an

The workaround is to pass these parameters to the kernel.

i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs

It's recommended to test before change definitily like this.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

This worked for me.